# How to update rails db records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app. I have a table User and a column Number which is a string. Some users saved their phone number with spaces (for example `1234 1234`) and now I want to remove the space from their phone numbers.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
space = " "
phones = User.where("number like ?", "%#{space}%").pluck(:number)
phones.each do |phone|
  phone = phone.gsub(/\s+/, "")
  phone.save
end
```

I got the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'save'` How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the `user` object to save it. Read inline comments below

```
space = " "
users = User.where("number like ?", "%#{space}%") # collect users with number having space character here. 
# then iterate on those users
users.each do |user|
  user.number = user.number.gsub(/\s+/, "") # notice here, changing the phone number of that user
  user.save # and saving that user with the updated `number`
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You `pluck` data from User table. Thus, `phones` variable contains a `number` array not **USER** objects. You can't use `save` on a array element. That's why the error occurs. 
You can do the following:

```
space = " "
phones = User.where("number like ?", "%#{space}%")
phones.each do |phone|
  phone.number = phone.number.gsub(/\s+/, "")
  phone.save
end
```

Comment: Where does it say `phone` responds to methods `number` and `save`?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh He is trying to pluck `number` attribute from the **User** table. Thus, we may assume that the `phone` in the loop contains a number attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could do is create a rake task to update the existing records on the system.

```
namespace :update do
  desc 'Strip space from existing numbers from Users'
  task(:number => ::environment) do
   space = ' '
   numbers_with_space = User.where("number like ?", "%#{space}%")
   numbers_with_space.each do |a|
     a.number = a.number.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
     a.save(validate: false) # You would like to use 
                             # validate false in order
                             # to stop other validation from updating the record.
   end
end
```

Then execute the rake task.

```
bundle exec rake update:number
```

Another way to handle this beforehand can be through reformatting number during validation. This way you'll not need to run the rake task or code to reformat and save when new data are entered in app.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 before_validation :reformat_number, on: [:create, :update]

 private

 def reformat_number
   self.number.gsub!(/\s+/, '')
 end
end
```

Comment: Please also include the part to update existing phone numbers with spaces. That is the actual problem of OP.

Comment: Updated the answer.